# flowground HTTP Reply Connector "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Tags: flowground

Based on a webhook connector my flowground flow gets data from a REST-API (rest-api-component) and passes it through via HTTP-Replay connector.

The Mapping Result in my HTTP-Reply connector shows the correct response in HTML, but firefox shows the error:

> JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

The crazy thing is, when I inspect the plain response, the HTML is delivered correctly from the flowground webhook...

[screenshot of flow setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTxnq.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem:

by default the response header is **application/json**.

This can be changed in the *"Configure input"* tab to

> "text/html"